# Codeigniter4 - Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Startup::index

Tags: codeigniter-4

I'm trying to loading view by code below:

Controller:

```
<?php namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Startup extends Controller
{
   public function index()
   {
        return view('install/startup');
   }
}
```

Route:

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers');
$routes->setDefaultController('Startup');
$routes->setDefaultMethod('index');
$routes->setTranslateURIDashes(false);
$routes->set404Override();
$routes->setAutoRoute(true);
```

When loading I've got 404 error message: Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Startup::index

please see image 
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlv98.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your image showing your folder structure, you have your Startup controller under a install folder, so you need to factor that in.

Your Startup Controller needs to be... (Note the namespace)

```
<?php
namespace App\Controllers\Install;
use CodeIgniter\Controller;

class Startup extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        return view('\App\Views\install\startup.php');
    }
}
```

And if you want to set this as your "default", your Routes need to be

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers\Install');
$routes->setDefaultController('Startup');
```

Note: No Route Definitions are set... I.E no $routes->get()... are defined

Namespace is your friend, so if you are going to put things under other folders you need to make your namespace values match.

**UPDATE: Please NOTE.** I have changed the Controllers/install folder to be Controllers/Install ( Using a Capital I for Install ). Case Matters...

So in your case you would use

```
$routes->setDefaultNamespace('App\Controllers\install'); // LOWER CASE install.
$routes->setDefaultController('Startup');
```

Case Matters.

Comment: You wrote: I follow your instructions, but it’s still not working and get error messages Controller or its method is not found: \App\Controllers\Install\Startup::index Even I comment out Route Definition.

Comment: I may have set your Controllers/install folder to Controllers/Install ( Capital I ).